# Github: merging from master back into feature branch

Tags: git, github-for-windows

I have two questions:

1. Does `github` for Windows use the `--no-ff` flag for merging ?
2. I have a few branches:

   - `master` branch: holds the latest official version
   - `development` branch: holds the lastest dev version
   - "feature" branches, namely `dbObjects` and `startMenu`

Now, I have updated dbObjects and startMenu and merged them into `development`.
The `development` branch works just fine. However, the two branches (`dbObject` and `startMenu`) don't have the latest version: `startMenu` doesn't have `dbObject`'s updates and vice-versa.

I have more development on `startMenu` and `dbObjects` branches to do, so it's important for me to update those branches as well. Should I merge `development` into each one of them, or is there some other way to do it in Git?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: startMenu and dbObject will be shared on origin. is it safe to use re-base in that case?

Answer (score 2):

1/ No

The one place where GitHub for Windows could specify using a `no-ff` for merge is in the "system" config file, that is the config file from the git distribution embedded in GitHub for Windows.

You can find it in:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\GitHub\Portable_Git_xxxxx\etc\gitconfig
```

For instance:

```
C:\Users\VonC\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_64179092f39f5dacb60dcab147fb4d04266c0eae\etc\gitconfig
```

And it doesn't contain:

```
[merge]
  ff = false
```

(which would force a merge commit)

2/ I agree with the rebase.

As long as you don't already have pushed those branches to GitHub (or even if you have, but nobody else has cloned that GitHub repo), you always can rebase your feature branches on top of the updated `development` branch.

See "[git rebase vs git merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/804178/6309)" for more.

Comment: thanks VonC. for 2. what if i share those edited branches over github ? before the merge? i read some where that i should be careful using re-base on shared branches

Comment: @oak if nobody else cloned that branch, you can `git push --force`. More on that on http://stackoverflow.com/a/8940299/6309, alternatives on http://stackoverflow.com/q/11058312/6309